# {{if}} of jQuery template not working in visual studio

Tags: jquery, visual-studio, jquery-templates

I have code as follows

```
<select id="TaskStatusDropdown">
    <option value="1" {{if TaskStatus == 1}}selected="selected"{{/if}}>Not Started</option>
    <option value="2">Pending</option>
    <option value="3">Complete</option>
</select>
```

The problem is that the {{if}} is not working, i.e. i get message in visual studio that "Attribute name must be followed by = sign and value. If the value is in quotation marks, the quotation marks must match"

Is this anything specific to visual studio or do i have the syntax incorrect?

Comment: you are not closing the `if` statement `{{if TaskStatus == 1}}selected="selected"{{/if}}`

Comment: sorry forgot to add, even after closing the {{if}} still does not work.

Answer (score 1):

In you code you do not have the closing tag for if condition. So you should close the if condition like this

```
{{if}} {{/if}}
```

Answer (score 0):

This message is just a validation warning because the template is not html valid.
You can move it to a script tag with type `text/x-jquery-tmpl` but you'll lose the syntax highlight

```
<script type="text/x-jquery-tmpl" id="TaskStatusDropdown">
   <select>
      <option value="1" {{if TaskStatus == 1}}selected="selected"{{/if}}>Not Started</option>
      <option value="2">Pending</option>
      <option value="3">Complete</option>
   </select>
</script>
```

or just ignore the message. There is no type in VS for the jQuery template syntax.

If the condition in the template is not working that means there is something wrong with other things. So paste code with `.tmpl` call and in which files do you keep template (`.cshtml, .html`)? Is it in `<script>` tag or not?